# Extract values before and after position in a python list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to conditionally extract values from a python list based on following logic:

```
ll = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]
```

I want to extract 3 values before and after a given value. e.g. if input is 2007, then 3 values before it will be: 2004, 2005, 2006 and after will be: 2008, 2009, 2010. If input is 2014, then I want to extract 5 values before and 1 value after (for a total of 6 values).

I can do this using for loops but is there a more pythonic solution?

Comment: Yes, you can do this using slices. Here is a good reference: https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html

The actual values of these slices will need to be computed. As you said, you always want 6 list items. However, if it is at the end of the list, you do not want to wrap around.

Comment: @CarlesMitjans, yes it will be always ordered and you can assume a step size of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slicing:

```
>>> ll = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]
>>> idx = ll.index(2002)
>>> ll[max(idx-5,0):idx+2]
[2001, 2002, 2003]
>>> idx = ll.index(2013)
>>> ll[max(idx-5,0):idx+2]
[2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]
```

Answer (score 1):

List slicing is made just for this, as mentioned by Daniel. Since what you are asking for is not a standard use case, you gotta write your own functions. I found two ways to do it.

The first simply distinguishes five possible cases and applies the list slicing accordingly. Note that the if-series here only works because the return statements exit the function. It's basically equivalent to if-else.

The second function has fewer lines of code by using `ll.remove()` smartly but it's a little harder to understand.

Either one will work.

```py
ll = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010,
      2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]

def six_neighbours_simple(year):
    idx = ll.index(year) # get location of year in array
    # take care of the left end
    if idx == 0:
        return ll[1:7]
    if idx < 3:
        return ll[:idx] + ll[idx+1:7]
    # take care of the right end
    if idx == len(ll) - 1:
        return ll[-7:-1]
    if idx > len(ll) - 4:
        return ll[-7:idx] + ll[idx+1:]
    # ELSE
    return ll[idx-3:idx] + ll[idx+1:idx+4]

def six_neighbours_short(yr):
    idx = ll.index(yr) # save location of yr
    years = ll[:] # copy list into new variable so we don't change it
    years.remove(yr) # remove selected year
    left_slice = idx-3 # start of range
    left_slice = min(max(0,left_slice),len(years)-6) # account for edges
    right_slice = left_slice+6 # end of range is straightforward now
    return years[left_slice:right_slice]
```